# Access protected object using reflection

Tags: php

I have the following printed to my screen:

```
array(1) {
  [120]=>
  object(EE_Datetime)#4364 (8) {
    ["_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor":protected]=>
    array(12) {
      ["DTT_ID"]=>
      string(3) "120"
      ["EVT_ID"]=>
      string(4) "2152"
      ["DTT_name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["DTT_description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["DTT_EVT_start"]=>
      string(19) "2016-06-19 07:00:00"
```

I need to access the `DTT_EVT_start` key, but as you can see the object is protected. What is the best solution here which will allow me to access the key in question? I'm aware of the Reflection classes, but I'm not sure if that is the best approach here. Thanks

Comment: Could you create a method in the class to return the value?

Comment: Unfortunaltey not the class is third party and I'm unable to update it

Comment: You can either use Reflection or (better, I think), extend the class and write new method(s) to work with the protected member(s).

Answer (score 0):

`_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor` is an `Array` property so all you need is to get it with reflection, change it visibility and get it value

```
class TestClass
{
    protected $_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor = [];

    public function __construct($arr)
    {
        $this->_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor = $arr;
    }
}
```

and the code:

```
$t = new TestClass(['DTT_EVT_start' => 'some date']);
$refl = new ReflectionClass($t);
$property = $refl->getProperty('_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$values = $property->getValue($t);
echo $values['DTT_EVT_start'];
```